# Why is this loop changed?

Tags: java, loops, optimization

I just encountered this decompiled class file of my class:

**MyClass**

```
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println("line: " + line);
    if (i == 0) {
        colArr = line.split(Pattern.quote("|"));

    } else {
        i++;
    }
}
```

The `while` loop has been changed to a `for` loop in the class file:

**Decompiled MyClass**

```
for (String[] colArr = null; (line = reader.readLine()) != null; ++i) {
    System.out.println("line: " + line);
    if (i == 0) {
        colArr = line.split(Pattern.quote("|"));
    } else {
    }
}
```

Why has this loop been changed to a `for`?
I think it might be another way of code optimization by the compiler, I could be wrong.
I just wanted to know if it is, what advantages does a `for` loop provide over a `while` loop or other loop?
What is the category of such code optimizations?

Comment: Hard to tell from source code along, but it might just be a choice of the decompiler to show you this version. Note that a decompiler has to "guess" a bit - it chooses one possible source code that might lead to the given bytecode.

Comment: So, it is a compiler optimization, then?

Comment: I'm feeling too lazy to decompile your code, but it might be the case that there is no difference between the bytecode generated by a while loop and a for loop in some cases and therefore your IDE just picks one of them to show you the code. I don't see how that could be an optimization in this case.

Comment: please note that both loops are not complete, they are either missing entire statements of at least the closing brackets.

Comment: @KumarAnkit - No necessarily *optimization*, no. There isn't a one-to-one relationship between source constructs and bytecode. That's what Hulk means when he/she says "a decompiler has to 'guess' a bit."

Comment: So, it can also depend on the code enclosed by the loops? How does this optimization work?

Comment: @KumarAnkit what people are trying to explain is that maybe there's no optimization at all. Try translating a hindi (or whatever is your regional dialect) sentence in english using Google translate, and then back to hindi. You'll be lucky if it's the same sentence than at the beginning. Here it's the same thing, got it?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, When you say "a decompiler has to 'guess'", does it mean the decompiler actually guesses what could have been the actual code? Can it not read the code? So, does it mean these loops are identical at the byte-code level?

Comment: @KumarAnkit - `for` (and `while`, etc.) don't exist at the bytecode level. It's jump instructions, assignments, etc. One decompiler might look at some bytecode and say "that looks like a `for`" while another might look at it and say "that looks like a `while`". *"So, does it mean these loops are identical at the byte-code level?"* Not necessarily. If you compile the code output by a decompiler, you don't necessarily end up with identical bytecode. In fact, I suspect you rarely would.

Comment: @dici, thanks, I can understand this language as well.  I got that it does not mean optimization, was just little bit surprised to have found it

Comment: @ernest_k considering that the two loops are probably intended to have identical behaviour I suspect that you ended the else clause on the wrong line.

Comment: @Taemyr Possibly. But there was no statement removed. Just added closing braces to make it more readable (I believe `i++;` being moved to the loop declaration is part of the compiler-made changes)

Comment: OP must be hiding something from us. The two snippets are not equivalent. The first one will never update `i` once it's equal to zero, so it may set the value of `colArr` multiple times in a reasonable scenario. The second one will update `colArr` only once.

Comment: @ach, you are correct where you reason that both logic are not the same logic, but no, not hiding code here, it is just that I had to clarify the loop(s), so to keep it concise I ommitted some irrelevant lines.

Comment: @KumarAnkit: Some of the lines you thought are irrelevant are very important

Answer (score 45):

In this situation changing `while()` to `for()` is not an optimization. There is simply no way to know from bytecode which one was used in a source code.

There are many situations when:

```
while(x)
```

is the same as:

```
for(;x;)
```

Suppose we have a three similar java applications - one with `while()` statement, and two with corresponting `for()`. First `for()` with  stopping criterion only like in the standard `while()`, and second `for()` also with iterator declaration and incrementation.

**APPLICATION #1 - SOURCE**

```
public class While{
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int i = 0;
        while(i<5){
            System.out.println(i);
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

**APPLICATION #2 - SOURCE**

```
public class For{
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int i = 0;
        for(; i<5 ;){
            System.out.println(i);
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

**APPLICATION #3 - SOURCE**

```
public class For2{
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
}
```

If we compile all of them we have got:

**APPLICATION #1 - BYTECODE**

```
public class While {
  public While();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: return

  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    Code:
       0: iconst_0
       1: istore_1
       2: iload_1
       3: iconst_5
       4: if_icmpge     20
       7: getstatic     #2                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
      10: iload_1
      11: invokevirtual #3                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(I)V
      14: iinc          1, 1
      17: goto          2
      20: return
}
```

**APPLICATION #2 - BYTECODE**

```
public class For {
  public For();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: return

  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    Code:
       0: iconst_0
       1: istore_1
       2: iload_1
       3: iconst_5
       4: if_icmpge     20
       7: getstatic     #2                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
      10: iload_1
      11: invokevirtual #3                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(I)V
      14: iinc          1, 1
      17: goto          2
      20: return
}
```

**APPLICATION #3 - BYTECODE**

```
public class For2 extends java.lang.Object{
public For2();
  Code:
   0:   aload_0
   1:   invokespecial   #1; //Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
   4:   return

public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
  Code:
   0:   iconst_0
   1:   istore_1
   2:   iload_1
   3:   iconst_5
   4:   if_icmpge       20
   7:   getstatic       #2; //Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
   10:  iload_1
   11:  invokevirtual   #3; //Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(I)V
   14:  iinc    1, 1
   17:  goto    2
   20:  return

}
```

So you can see, there is no difference associated with `for` and `while` usage.

Comment: Maybe you could put the actual bytecode of both snippets in your answer to prove your point :p it's the intuitive answer, but it doesn't mean it's right

Comment: @Dici I've put a sample for better explanation.

Comment: @dgebert +1.   :p

Comment: I like this answer: I think the demonstration can be improved by moving the `i++` into the `for`-loop to make: `for(; i<5 ; i++){`. That way you can show that either way, the bytecode puts the `iinc` at the end of the loop body at the bytecode level, and so the decompiler can't always tell if the `i++` goes into the last field of the for loop or as the last statement in the loop body.

Comment: @mtraceur And, even better, put the initialising statement in the first part of the `for`.

Comment: @mtraceur @wizzwizz4 - I think it's better to add the third example to show also there is no difference with `for` from my first example, and `for` suggested by you. I  made an edit.

Answer (score 15):

As others have already pointed out: The decompiler (usually) cannot distinguish between different source codes that result in the same byte code.

Unfortunately, you did not provide the **full** code of the method. So the following contains some guesses about where and how this loop appears inside a method (and these guesses might, to some extent, distort the result).

But let's have a look at some roundtrips here. Consider the following class, containing methods with both versions of the code that you posted:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class DecompileExample {

    public static void methodA(BufferedReader reader) throws IOException {
        String line = null;
        int i = 0;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println("line: " + line);
            if (i == 0) {
                String[] colArr = line.split(Pattern.quote("|"));

            } else {
                i++;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void methodB(BufferedReader reader) throws IOException {
        String line = null;
        int i = 0;
        for (String[] colArr = null; (line = reader.readLine()) != null; ++i) {
            System.out.println("line: " + line);
            if (i == 0) {
                colArr = line.split(Pattern.quote("|"));
            } else {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Compiling it with

```
javac DecompileExample.java -g:none
```

will create the corresponding class file. (Note: The `-g:none` parameter will cause the compiler to omit all debug information. The debug information *might* otherwise be used by the decompiler to reconstruct a more verbatim version of the original code, particularly, including the original variable names)

Now looking at the byte code of both methods, with

```
javap -c DecompileExample.class
```

will yield the following:

```
  public static void methodA(java.io.BufferedReader) throws java.io.IOException;
    Code:
       0: aconst_null
       1: astore_1
       2: iconst_0
       3: istore_2
       4: aload_0
       5: invokevirtual #2                  // Method java/io/BufferedReader.readLine:()Ljava/lang/String;
       8: dup
       9: astore_1
      10: ifnull        61
      13: getstatic     #3                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
      16: new           #4                  // class java/lang/StringBuilder
      19: dup
      20: invokespecial #5                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder."<init>":()V
      23: ldc           #6                  // String line:
      25: invokevirtual #7                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
      28: aload_1
      29: invokevirtual #7                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
      32: invokevirtual #8                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.toString:()Ljava/lang/String;
      35: invokevirtual #9                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
      38: iload_2
      39: ifne          55
      42: aload_1
      43: ldc           #10                 // String |
      45: invokestatic  #11                 // Method java/util/regex/Pattern.quote:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;
      48: invokevirtual #12                 // Method java/lang/String.split:(Ljava/lang/String;)[Ljava/lang/String;
      51: astore_3
      52: goto          4
      55: iinc          2, 1
      58: goto          4
      61: return
```

and

```
  public static void methodB(java.io.BufferedReader) throws java.io.IOException;
    Code:
       0: aconst_null
       1: astore_1
       2: iconst_0
       3: istore_2
       4: aconst_null
       5: astore_3
       6: aload_0
       7: invokevirtual #2                  // Method java/io/BufferedReader.readLine:()Ljava/lang/String;
      10: dup
      11: astore_1
      12: ifnull        60
      15: getstatic     #3                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
      18: new           #4                  // class java/lang/StringBuilder
      21: dup
      22: invokespecial #5                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder."<init>":()V
      25: ldc           #6                  // String line:
      27: invokevirtual #7                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
      30: aload_1
      31: invokevirtual #7                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
      34: invokevirtual #8                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.toString:()Ljava/lang/String;
      37: invokevirtual #9                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
      40: iload_2
      41: ifne          54
      44: aload_1
      45: ldc           #10                 // String |
      47: invokestatic  #11                 // Method java/util/regex/Pattern.quote:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;
      50: invokevirtual #12                 // Method java/lang/String.split:(Ljava/lang/String;)[Ljava/lang/String;
      53: astore_3
      54: iinc          2, 1
      57: goto          6
      60: return
}
```

(There **is** a small difference: The `String[] colArr = null` is translated into an

```
aconst null
astore_3
```

at the beginning of the second version. But this is one of the aspects that is related to parts of the code that you have omitted in the question).

You did not mention which one you are using, but the JD-GUI decompiler from http://jd.benow.ca/ decompiles this into the following:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class DecompileExample
{
  public static void methodA(BufferedReader paramBufferedReader)
    throws IOException
  {
    String str = null;
    int i = 0;
    while ((str = paramBufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
    {
      System.out.println("line: " + str);
      if (i == 0) {
        String[] arrayOfString = str.split(Pattern.quote("|"));
      } else {
        i++;
      }
    }
  }

  public static void methodB(BufferedReader paramBufferedReader)
    throws IOException
  {
    String str = null;
    int i = 0;
    String[] arrayOfString = null;
    while ((str = paramBufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
    {
      System.out.println("line: " + str);
      if (i == 0) {
        arrayOfString = str.split(Pattern.quote("|"));
      }
      i++;
    }
  }
}
```

You can see that the code is the same for both cases (at least regarding the loop - there one more is a difference regarding the "dummy variables" that I had to introduce in order to compile it, but this is unrelated to the question, so to speak).

The **tl;dr** message is clear:

**Different** source codes can be compiled into the **same** byte code. Consequently, the **same** byte code can be decompiled into **different** source codes. But every decompiler has to settle for one version of the source code.

(A side note: I was a bit surprised to see that when compiling without `-g:none` (that is, when the debug information is retained), JD-GUI even somehow manages to reconstruct that the first one used a `while`-loop and the second one used a `for`-loop. But in general, and when the debug information is omitted, this is simply no longer possible).

Comment: I am using the IntelliJ IDEA, which uses the _fernflower_ decompiler. Thanks for the elaborated answer.

Comment: @KumarAnkit As indicated by the comments about the `-g:none` flag, the result does not only depend on the decompiler, but also on how the `.class` files are generated in the first place. (But I assume that IDEs will usually **not** omit the debug information - in the end, they are basically *intended* for retaining it in order to use it in some nice debugger UI)

Comment: +1 I think you can make it more clear by more explicitly emphasizing how the `i++` at the end of the source code's loop body and the `++i` at the end of the for-loop declaration map to the same instructions at the end of the bytecode's loop body.

Comment: @mtraceur Yes, more generally: I considered to make the initial code more "sensible", that is, actually *do* something sensible with `i` and the `colArr`. But at some point, this involved so many changes that I was afraid to bury the code that was posted *originally* under these changes. Not sure about the best solution for this. But if the question was updated with compileable code, I'd update the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 6):

That's basically because of the nature of bytecode. Java bytecode is something like assembly language, so there are no such things as `for` and `while` loop, there is simply jump instruction: `goto`. So there may be no difference between `while` and `for` loop, Both can be compiled to similar code and decompiler is just making guess.

Comment: While true, I think a good answer should make an analysis of the actual byte code. I don't have the motivation to do it now so I'll stick to comments, but just sayin'

Answer (score 5):

Both the **`for`** loop and the `while` loop code segments can be translated into similar machine code. After that when de-compiling the de-compiler has to pick one of the `two possible` scenarios.

I guess that is what's happening here.

simply:

```
compile(A) -> C

compile(B) -> C
```

So when you are given `C`, then there should be a guess to pick `A` or `B`

Comment: Maybe you could put the actual bytecode of both snippets in your answer to prove your point :p it's the intuitive answer, but it doesn't mean it's right